# Nothing appears in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, terminator

I am having a problem with the terminal of Ubuntu18.04 LTS. I'm using a dual boot on iMac with macOS.

The problem can be seen in the image below. I have no idea how to solve it. I have checked online and didn't find any solution.

I have tried other alternatives like terminator and VScode terminal, and they are also like this. I have also tried rebooting the PC and completely shutingdown and reopening. I'm working on a school project and I really need to figure this out.[image]

Thanks

Comment: have you tried zooming in or out? top menu the three line icon.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to fix without a working terminal to make the fixes in. What happens if you type `<CTRL><ALT><F3>`?

Comment: What happens when you type `bash` and the press ENTER? Also, PJ's suggestion should take you to a TTY screen where you should be able to log in with your username and password. Hopefully, you will be able to run commands from there. If this works, reply back with @PJSingh at the beginning of your comment so they will get a notification for your reply.

Comment: @mchid That's what confused me. It just became like a txt file. When I tyoe something and press enter, the cursor goes to the next line. That's it. Nothing happens when I type bash ad you asked too.

Comment: @PJ Singh I go to the tty screen when I do as you said. It looks like this after I put in my account information:  https://imgur.com/a/IKMBxNc. The problem persists here too and I can't run basic commands.

Comment: @pierrely yeah, noting happens when i try that.

Comment: Okay, fellow humans. I have solved the problem. Thank you for your help. I have provided how I solved it in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the problem. The problem happened when I added some lines to the ~/.bashrc file as part of ROS installation. I had to remove the part that is causing the problem, and it worked as before.

Comment: I was thinking the problem was either .bashrc or .profile. Remember to come back in a couple of days and accept your answer. This could be a common problem, so others will benefit from your experience and solution.

Comment: @PJ Singh Yeah, sure.